# Manifest merger failed for <receiver> when migrating to android 12 despite adding android: exported flag

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest, android-12

I am trying migrating my app to android 12 by changing the target SDK version to 31 in build.gradle.
As required, I have added `android:exported` flag to every activity/receiver/services/provider tags present in my manifest file. But still I am getting this error.

```
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
```

So I am guessing this issue is due to any 3rd party library whose manifest contains a receiver without `android:exported` flag.

I have also checked merged manifest file for missing `android:exported` in components of any third party libraries. But in merged manifest file also all activity/receiver/services tags has exported flag.

So how can I find that missing receiver which is causing the issue.

Comment: You can try to manually run gradle with `--debug` parameter and hope the log shows you which 3rd party library is processed when the error occurs.

Comment: @Robert, already tried that but no success.

Comment: Then you can try to check the app build directory for the merged manifest file. E.g. check `app/build/intermediates/merged_manifest` and `app/build/intermediates/packed_manifest` hopefully the merged manifest is first saved to disk and then checked for errors.

Comment: have u set `android:exported="fasle"` for receiver ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because some of the dependency libraries that you're using have elements which do not have "android:exported" attribute.

You need to do this:

- Lower the version in your gradle to 30 and sync and build.
- Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file and click on "Merged Manifest".
- Find items that don't have "android:exported" attribute.
- Then add them to your AndroidManifest.xml file in this way.

```
<activity
    android:name="SomeActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge"
    tools:replace="android:exported" />
```

Now you can increase your version to 31.